Moving my riverpods generated files to a dedicated folder
I'm doing some cleaning in my project, therefore I want to move my generated files to an other folder to improve the readability.
I've managed to move freezed files but not riverpod
This is my build.yaml
targets:
  $default:
    builders:
      source_gen|combining_builder:
        generate_for:
          - lib/**.dart
        options:
          build_extensions:
            '^lib/src/data/dtos/{{file}}.dart': 'lib/src/data/dtos/generated/{{file}}.g.dart'
      freezed|freezed:
        enabled: true
        options:
          build_extensions:
            '^lib/src/data/dtos/{{file}}.dart': 'lib/src/data/dtos/generated/{{file}}.freezed.dart'
      riverpod_generator:
        enabled: true
        options:
          build_extensions:
            '^lib/src/domain/states/{{file}}.dart': 'lib/src/domain/states/generated/{{file}}.g.dart'

part 'generated/my_notifier.g.dart'; in my notifiers
How can I move my riverpods file in a generated folder ?
I refered to https://github.com/rrousselGit/riverpod/blame/master/packages/riverpod_generator/build.yaml but didn't manage to make it work

I find it far simpler to just tell my IDE to hide the .g files (and other generated files) as a foldable entry.  Hidden most of the time, but easily examined if needed.

I want the project to be easily readable no matter the IDE the developer is working with. I'm not sure if people will use Android Studio or Code. But thanks for your suggestion, will do that for my personal projects

If I understand correctly, AS and VSC can both do that.  But the settings are different.

I forgot to put a riverpods entry on source_gen|combining_builder -> build_extensions set. It's working fine now
build.yaml
targets:
  $default:
    builders:
      source_gen|combining_builder:
        generate_for:
          - lib/**.dart
        options:
          build_extensions:
            {
              "lib/src/data/dtos/{{file}}.dart": "lib/src/data/dtos/generated/{{file}}.g.dart",
              "lib/src/domain/states/{{file}}.dart": "lib/src/domain/states/generated/{{file}}.g.dart",
            }
      freezed|freezed:
        options:
          build_extensions:
            "^lib/src/data/dtos/{{file}}.dart": "lib/src/data/dtos/generated/{{file}}.freezed.dart"
      riverpod_generator:
        options:
          provider_name_prefix: ""
          provider_family_name_prefix: ""
          provider_name_suffix: "Provider"
          provider_family_name_suffix: "Provider"



Based on one of the comments, I found a usable way to fold generated files under the original .dart file in Jetbrains (e.g. Intellij Idea).

In your Project view, select the "Options" vertical '...' icon.

In the dropdown, select "Appearance", then "File Nesting..."

Under the relevant file type (e.g. '.dart'), add associated generated or "child" file extensions to the list.  For example, .g.dart for riverpod or .freezed.dart for freezed.  Save / accept your changes.

Your files should now be nested correctly


